# Assembly into C, printf function

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have this assembly code and what I think it does is print using the `printf` function. i am not really familiar with C, but I created a main function and I printed out `printf("%d, %d", x, y)` where x and y are both zero.

I converted the C code to assembly but I got something totally different. Can somebody help me understand what the assembly code below does?

```
            mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)
            mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
            movl   $0x80486a0,(%esp)
            call   8048360 <printf@plt>
```

Comment: Assembly is different based upon the assembler and the architecture, it might be a good idea to say which you are using, and what C compiler...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a very literal translation of your assembly,

```
mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)
```

move the value in edx onto the stack at offset 8 (esp + 8)

```
mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
```

move the value in eax onto the stack at offset 4 (esp + 4)

```
movl   $0x80486a0,(%esp)
```

move [the 32bit value] 0x80486a0 onto the stack at offset 0

This is a very basic way that arguments to a function will be placed on the stack--RTL or C order. The value at the lowest offset is the first argument (in this case, the address of your string literal in memory), and the value at the highest offset is the last argument.

When you hit the call:

```
call   8048360 <printf@plt>
```

Your program will jump to the given address (which your disassembler has identified as the printf function), read the values from the stack, perform the print operation, and then return back to your code, resuming operation at the next instruction after your call.

I'm going to guess that your source looked something like this:

```
void main()
{
    int x =0, y=0;
    printf("%d, %d", x, y);
}
```

Depending on your OS/compiler, you might be guaranteed that eax and edx will have the value 0 at startup. Or you could be missing the initialization code from your snippet.

Comment: +1 for such a nice explanation. :)

Comment: thank you for you answer :D, but i have a question: what's the " initialization code from the snippet."

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of things, this puts three parameters onto the stack -- two ints coming from `edx` and `eax`, plus what looks like an address -- presumably the address it picked to store the string literal (i.e., the format string). After that, it calls `printf`.

So, the bottom line is that it looks like a pretty straightforward implementation of the source code you gave in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)` : Is moving edx's Value to Stack Pointer(with 0x8 offset).
`mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)` : Refer above.
`movl   $0x80486a0,(%esp)` : Is loading the address 0x80486a0 in the stack pointer.
`call   8048360 <printf@plt>`: Is calling the function printf.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have a question. I still do not understand how this line is done in my code: movl $0x80486a0,(%esp) : Is loading the address 0x80486a0 in the stack pointer.

Comment: It's not your code that is doing such, it's the standard way of calling a function. Whenever you call any function, this is the way it is executed at the assembly level. The stack pointer is filled with the starting address of the function so that the system knows which line of code to execute next. When the code loads the stack pointer with the address 0x80486a0, it means, the code residing at the address `0x80486a0` in the memory, will be executed next.